# Find out if a Ruby object implements a method that accepts a certain amount of arguments

Tags: ruby

I want to find out if I can call a method `count` with exactly 0 arguments:

```
@object.count()
```

on `@object` without raising an error. Is there a method that can give me that information?

In case there isn't, is anything wrong with implementing it like so:

```
begin
  count = @object.count()
  # Do anything with the information
rescue ArgumentError => e
end
```

Answer (score 3):

First: Checking the number of arguments of a method sounds like there is something wrong.
Second you are looking for "arity":

```
@object.method(:count).arity
```

Before you might want to check if the object responds to the given method.

```
@object.respond_to?(:count) && @object.method(:count).arity == 0
```

Be aware that if the method takes a variable number of arguments the arity is not that intuitive:

> For Ruby methods that take a variable number of arguments, returns
>   -n-1, where n is the number of required arguments. For methods written in C, returns -1 if the call takes a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

We can rephrase the question as: does the method have any required parameters? Or: Are none of the parameters required?

```
@object.method(:count).parameters.none? {|type, _| [:req, :keyreq].include?(type) }
```

This will allow you to catch methods which have optional parameters with default arguments, methods which have optional keyword parameters with default values, and methods which have optional rest parameters.

I find `parameters` much easier to deal with than the heavily overloaded single integer return value of `arity`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `arity` method:

```
@object.method(:count).arity
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-arity